# raw_input alternative for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a server application and I would like to be able to write commands like `start server`, `stop server`, `broadcast("clients","Hello")` in to my application but I can't figure out how to do it in node.

I do know how it would look inside python.

```
while on == 1:
    cmd = raw_input("user> ")
    if cmd == "start server":
        startserver()
    elif cmd == "stop server":
        stopserver()
        on = 0
```

I have seen some npm modules for this but they require me to write arguments, I want to make this a console type application.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for referencing python. Only for that reason I stumbled upon this answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a snippet that was recently removed from [commander.js](https://github.com/visionmedia/commander.js/commit/bf5e1f5ec9fb1af23dd873117558575cd01d7415). Something along these lines should work.

```
process.stdout.write("user> ");
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf8');
process.stdin.once('data', function(val){
    //look at val here and execute startserver() et al accordingly
}).resume();
```

Comment: That works but I have one problem, after I execute a command I want to be able to execute another, and for some reason it wont work if I put it in a loop, when I do it just spam's user >.

Comment: I fixed my problem by calling the function with in the function. Thanks :)

Comment: I believe process.stdin is initially paused so the resume starts it.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/command-line/how-to-prompt-for-command-line-input) explains exactly what you need